# Finding maximum number of AWS spot instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to figure out a way to find the number of spot instances I could launch in an availability zone without actually attempting the launch. I want to know the absolute maximum number of the instances, assuming I'm specifying the maximum price allowed for the instance type. I am also not limited to the standard spot instance limits (support raised those for me).

The reason is that I want to estimate the maximum amount of instances I could run in a zone if I did not care about the possible price spikes.

I do not think there is an API to get this information; I wonder if this was researched by somebody and the data is available publicly.

Comment: If you might actually launch anywhere close to the max on a regular basis, Amazon will probably create an API jut for you :-)

Comment: My reasoning is that some workloads are too big for one AZ and causes prices to spike up to my maximum, but others AZs/regions may be larger. So I want to be able to choose the AZ that can fit my workload on spot instances. And if I choose a big enough one, there is a higher chance that I won't actually have to pay the maximum as there will still be cheap instances available.

Comment: If you are a heavy spot instance user you might just be able to email your Account Rep and ask. " Could I launch 1000 spot instances in this zone?"  or "Which AZ has the most spot capacity?" Keep in mind the limit that is on your account exists to prevent single users from creating so many instances that they affect other customers in an overly negative way.

Comment: This article might give you some ideas to ponder.  "Hamilton said each AWS region has at least two availability zones and at least one datacenter if not more, and then added that a typical datacenter has at least 50,000 servers and sometimes more than 80,000 servers. "    http://www.enterprisetech.com/2014/11/14/rare-peek-massive-scale-aws/